# rails has_and_belongs_to_many update create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :topics
end
```

I make a model for create them both.

```
class Forms::NewTopic
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :title, :user_id, :raw_link, :description, :tags

  def save
    topic_tags = []
    @tags.gsub(/\s+/m, ' ').strip.split(" ").uniq.each do |tag_name|
      tag = Tag.find_or_create_by name: tag_name
      topic_tags << tag if tag.errors.blank?
      break if topic_tags.count == 3
    end

    Topic.create title:       @title,
                 user_id:     @user_id,
                 raw_link:    @raw_link,
                 description: @description,
                 tags:        topic_tags
  end

end
```

But when I want to update them, I cannot find some better solution.

Is there a better solution to solve the scene? Thx :)

Comment: You want to update them means.?

Comment: And we should never create create a separate model to create associations. We can improve this definitely, I will tell you how

Comment: Why are you doing the creations in the model. This can be done in the controller plus the rest of the logic can be moved to a helper